# JUnit test fail when method throw exception even try catch

Tags: android, junit4

## What should I suppose to do to verify below case?

**Note**

I have try `@Test(expected = NumberFormatException.class)` but no hope. Also, it looks like some people remove try/catch block and mark it at method signature instead (why don't we handle it if we know)

**Tested code**

```
public class CalculatorViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    Calculator calculator;
    String inputCheckAmount;
    String inputTipPercentage;
    TipCalculator tipCalculation;

    public CalculatorViewModel(Calculator calculator) {
        this.calculator = calculator;
        this.tipCalculation = new TipCalculator("", 0, 0,0, 0);

        if (calculator == null) {
            this.calculator = new Calculator();
        }
    }

    public void calculateTip() {

        try {
            double checkAmount = Double.parseDouble(inputCheckAmount);
            int tipPercentage = Integer.parseInt(inputTipPercentage);
            tipCalculation = calculator.calculatorTip(checkAmount, tipPercentage);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**In test class..**

```
public class CalculatorViewModelTest {

    CalculatorViewModel viewModel;

    @Mock
    Calculator mockCalculator;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        viewModel = new CalculatorViewModel(mockCalculator);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCalculateTipBadTipPercentage() {
        // Arrange
        viewModel.inputCheckAmount = "10.00";
        viewModel.inputTipPercentage = "";

        // Act
        viewModel.calculateTip();

        // Asset
        verify(mockCalculator, never()).calculatorTip(anyDouble(), anyInt());
    }
}
```

**Error Log**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.viinsoft.playground.mvvmmytipcalculator.viewmodel.CalculatorViewModel.calculateTip(CalculatorViewModel.java:26)
    at com.viinsoft.playground.mvvmmytipcalculator.viewmodel.CalculatorViewModelTest.testCalculateTipBadTipPercentage(CalculatorViewModelTest.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:19)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Comment: you don't signal outside of the method that there was an error (number format exception). Declare it in the method signature so that the callers have to deal with it, or make the result of calculation `Optional` so that the caller knows things went badly.

Comment: try to use --> viewModel.calculateTip().test().assertError {
      //check exception here 
    }